# Query regarding Canonical Orientation in Graphx Triangle Count

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have read many articles along with Spark own documentation which says Graphx  Triangle Count requires Graph to be Canonically Orientated. About canonical orientation, it is described as for an edge source_id < dest_id.

With following three edges in graph,

```
edges.add(new Edge<String>(1, 2, "Friend"));
edges.add(new Edge<String>(2, 3, "Advisor"));
edges.add(new Edge<String>(1, 3, "Friend"));
```

It shows that nodes 1,2,3 has one triangle associated with it which makes sense. However, even If I change the direction of edges as follows, the result remains same.

```
edges.add(new Edge<String>(2, 1, "Friend"));
    edges.add(new Edge<String>(3, 2, "Advisor"));
    edges.add(new Edge<String>(3, 1, "Friend"));
```

This is puzzling me because in this case, source_id of edge is greater than dest_id. Could someone please explain this concept?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are executing the Triangle Count algorithm within GraphX. If you are just calling `TriangleCount.run` then GraphX canonicalizes the graph for you, more specifically, the `.run` method looks like this:

```
  def run[VD: ClassTag, ED: ClassTag](graph: Graph[VD, ED]): Graph[Int, ED] = {
    // Transform the edge data something cheap to shuffle and then canonicalize
    val canonicalGraph = graph.mapEdges(e => true).removeSelfEdges().convertToCanonicalEdges()
    // Get the triangle counts
    val counters = runPreCanonicalized(canonicalGraph).vertices
    // Join them bath with the original graph
    graph.outerJoinVertices(counters) { (vid, _, optCounter: Option[Int]) =>
      optCounter.getOrElse(0)
    }
  }
```

Notice that the run method calculates the canonical orientation of the graph and then runs. Furthermore, even if you called `graph.triangleCount()` this method just invokes `TriangleCount.run` from above:

```
def triangleCount(): Graph[Int, ED] = {
  TriangleCount.run(graph)
}
```

I believe this is why your code returns the same value no matter which way you orient the edges. As to why GraphX requires the canonical orientation, I am not quite sure. There are two reasons I can think of:

1. The algorithm requires specific partitioning across the cluster since the "canonicalization" of the graph runs a repartitioning of the graph.
2. The `edgeFunc` within the `runPreCanonicalized` function assumes/requires the edges to be canonical.

You should be aware that the `.run` method can be expensive. The documentation explicitly states that the "canonicalization procedure is costly as it requires repartitioning the graph. If the input data is already in 'canonical form' with self cycles removed then the `TriangleCount.runPreCanonicalized` should be used instead."

I hope this was helpful :)

Comment: This is really helpful.  :)